# VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN get 400 error on committing C# code file

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have setup a Subversion machine in our office LAN. Subversion is served by Apache.

Then I started a Java project and performed some migration from CVS (all Java projects!). It all ran fine, I can clearly use SVN from Eclipse using Subversive.

Then I started our first C# project. When committing it to Subversion, I always get a 400 error when Tortoise (driven by VisualSVN or used stand-alone) tries to upload a `.cs` file

TortoiseSVN version info (as of today, it is up to date):

```
TortoiseSVN 1.8.5, Build 25224 - 64 Bit , 2014/02/18 20:05:11↩⏎
Subversion 1.8.8, -release↩⏎
apr 1.5.0↩⏎
apr-util 1.5.3↩⏎
serf 1.3.4↩⏎
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014↩⏎
zlib 1.2.8
```

Here is TortoiseSVN log (partially localized):

```
Errore: Commit fallito (seguono dettagli):  
Errore: Unexpected HTTP status 400 'Bad request' on  
Errore:  '/svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-y/path/to/trunk/XsdValidationService/XmlValidationResult.cs'  
Errore: Additional errors:  
Errore: PUT of  
Errore:  '/svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-y/path/to/trunk/XsdValidationService/XmlValidationResult.cs':  
Errore:  400 Bad request
```

Here is Apache configuration

default-server.conf

```
<Location /svnroot/repo>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /srv/svn/repos/repo
  SVNAutoversioning On
  # Repository Display Name
  SVNReposName "SVN Repository"

  #SecFilterEngine off

  #Authorization
  # Do basic password authentication in the clear
  AuthType Basic

  # The name of the protected area or "realm"
  AuthName "CompanyName"

  # Make LDAP the authentication mechanism
  AuthBasicProvider ldap

  # Active Directory requires an authenticating DN to access records
  AuthLDAPBindDN []

  # This is the password for the AuthLDAPBindDN user in Active Directory
  AuthLDAPBindPassword []

  # The LDAP query URL
  AuthLDAPURL []

# Require a valid user
  Require valid-user
  AuthUserFile /dev/null

  allow from all
</Location>
```

Here is Apache access log

```
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "MKCOL /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/project/XsdValidationService HTTP/1.1" 201 71 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "MKCOL /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/projectProperties HTTP/1.1" 201 71 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "MKCOL /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/projectSchemas HTTP/1.1" 201 71 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "PROPPATCH /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/project/XsdValidationService HTTP/1.1" 207 491 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "PROPPATCH /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/project HTTP/1.1" 207 470 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "PUT /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/project/EDWin.sln HTTP/1.1" 201 71 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "PUT /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/projectSchemas/ED-AUTO-1-0.xsd HTTP/1.1" 201 71 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "PUT /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/projectSchemas/ED-ACC-SME-1-0.xsd HTTP/1.1" 201 71 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "PUT /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/projectSchemas/ED-RMBS-1-7.xsd HTTP/1.1" 201 71 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:09 +0100] "PUT /svnroot/cst/!svn/txr/21-w/path/to/projectXmlValidationResult.cs HTTP/1.1" 400 5268 "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
192.168.0.167 - [USERNAME] [07/Mar/2014:17:20:10 +0100] "DELETE /svnroot/cst/!svn/txn/21-w HTTP/1.1" 204 - "-" "SVN/1.8.8 (x64-microsoft-windows) serf/1.3.4 TortoiseSVN-1.8.5.25224"
```

I have no error displayed in error log.

I noticed that if Tortoise, for some reason, commits files in a different order, only the first `.cs` causes troubles. I have not implemented any filter hook script yet.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the exact wording of the error message in TortoiseSVN? Is there any proxy server between the Subversion server and your machine? E.g. IIS acting as reverse-proxy?

Comment: I just updated the question with TSVN error. Server is in LAN. While THERE IS a transparent proxy on our LAN, it shouldn't be currently used for LAN transfers.

Comment: And, even if the proxy manipulates requests, those arrive to Apache server as I can find logs there.

Comment: Found a hint: Wireshark reports that the error page is generated by Mono. Maybe there is an inconsistent configuration so that Apache doesn't use the DAV handler and uses the Mono handler for .cs file. Mono module is not loaded, but maybe some configuration is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `default-server.conf` contains the following directive (along with the comments):

```
# Include all *.conf files from /etc/apache2/conf.d/.
#
# This is mostly meant as a place for other RPM packages to drop in their
# configuration snippet.
# 
# You can comment this out here if you want those bits include only in a
# certain virtual host, but not here.
#
IncludeOptional /etc/apache2/conf.d/*.conf
```

In my openSUSE 13.1 installation, Apache comes with Mono. Though `mod_mono` is not loaded in `/etc/sysconfig/apache2` (`a2dismod mono` command), the `/etc/apache2/mod_mono.conf` always loads Mono runtime and associates, in particular, `.cs` files to Mono.

Now, when I commit C# code files, with `.cs` extension, Apache by default lets Mono handle those requests, which ultimately causes the following exception that can be captured only using Wireshark:

```
[System.ArgumentException]: Directory does not exists
Parameter name: value

  at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_Path (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileSystemWatcher:set_Path (string)
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.SetupOfflineWatch () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.Process (System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest req) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.RealProcessRequest (System.Object o) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.MonoWorkerRequest.ProcessRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

An ASP.NET exception in a Subversion request smelled enough bad to let me investigate

## Ultimately

I simply commented out the above Apache directive and commited without problems.